# Applications or Ways to Import MySQL Database with Relations etc..?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to edit my MySQL database after a long time of taking a rest, and I'm pretty confused what's what. Do you know of any application or a way in which I could import or merge my db on server into an application that will not only allow me to work with the database on my local pc, but be able to view the structure and relations visually?

Thank you :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL Workbench [1]. There you can generate a ERD (=Model) from your remote and/or local MySql Database. Furthermore you can manage your user accounts, edit tables and datas and much much more...

[1]... http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Hey Chris, I just replied to vikki with this problem I am having with MySQL workbench. The credentials I used are fine and I don't have a firewall on my pc. The sys admin at my hosting said it should work :/ 
http://i.imgur.com/Mqj1n.gif

Comment: @pufAmuf, have you tried to connect to a local sql server? So you could exclude router/firewall probs...

Comment: Hmm, if I understand correctly, no. I'm not running any servers on my pc. What I'm also willing to do is to export the database and import it inside the application. Would a .sql file retain all of the relations?

Comment: @pufAmuf were you able to export?

Comment: Yes. I exported the database to sql and then subsequently opened it in MySQl workbench. When I'll make structural changes, I'll just flush all of the info on the server and reupload the new mysql file.

Comment: @pufAmuf, I had the same problem a few years ago. I guess this depends that your ISP hosts the sql server in intranet. So your app on your webserver can access the sql server but you can't do it from outside. I solved it by exporting the database dump (.sql) and importing it into the workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Head on over here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
The Mysql Workbench included in the installer should help

Comment: Thanks vikki. However I am having issues with connecting to the db while the network admin at my server says the credentials I used are fine. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Mqj1n.gif